# Cardinality of the Euclidean topology and the axiom of choice

Tags: general-topology, set-theory, cardinals, axiom-of-choice

It is relatively straightforward to prove that the Euclidean topology has the same cardinality as the space itself.
I have sketched a proof below.
The proof seems to rely quite heavily on the axiom of choice.
I'm perfectly fine with (countable) dependent choice — I want to be able to define sequences recursively, for example — but one doesn't usually need more choice for topology in Euclidean spaces.

**Is dependent choice enough to show that the topology of $\mathbb R^n$, $n\geq1$, has the same cardinality as $\mathbb R^n$?**
If yes, how to prove it?
If not, how much do we know about the cardinality of the topology?
It seems that the cardinality of the topology lies between $\mathfrak{c}$ and $2^{\mathfrak{c}}$, but are there tighter bounds?

Proof of equal cardinalities with choice:
Let $T$ be the topology of $\mathbb R^n$ and $B$ a countable basis for it (rational balls, for example).
Since $|2^B|=|\mathbb R^n|$, it suffices to find an injection $f:\mathbb R^n\to T$ and a surjection $g:2^B\to T$.
These together will establish $|\mathbb R^n|\leq|T|\leq|2^B|=|\mathbb R^n|$ and the conclusion follows.
(Alternatively, the surjection $g$ has an injective right inverse, and we thus have injections both ways between $\mathbb R^n$ and $T$. The existence of a bijection follows from the Schröder–Bernstein theorem.)
We can simply take $f(x)=B(x,1)$ and $g(A)=\bigcup_{U\in A}U$.

Injecting $\mathbb R^n$ to $T$ requires no choice and always $T\subset 2^{\mathbb R^n}$, so at least $\mathfrak{c}\leq|T|\leq2^{\mathfrak{c}}$ without AC.
Without choice, I can't compare cardinals so easily or produce injective right inverses for surjections, so my proof falls apart.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The argument does not really use the axiom of choice.

Fix a countable basis $\{B_n\mid n\in\Bbb N\}$, now note the following is true.

> If $U,V$ are open subsets of $\Bbb R^n$, then $U=V$ if and only if $\{n\mid B_n\subseteq U\}=\{m\mid B_m\subseteq V\}$.

This gives us an injection from the open sets to subsets of $\Bbb N$. Now using Cantor-Bernstein, which holds without choice, we're done.

Comment: That's clever, thanks! As usual, it is obvious now that I've seen it...

Comment: Dangit, beat me to it!

Comment: @Noah: I'd say it's by luck if it makes you feel any better! :-P

Comment: Now you two are forcing me to decide which one of two essentially identical answers to accept. It's a finite choice, but I don't know if I can do it...

Comment: @Joonas: It is a well-known fact that one of the factors in the increase of depression in modern society is the over abundance of choice.

Comment: @AsafKaragila specifically, what is the rule for this injection from the open sets to subsets of $\mathbb{N}$? And what is the injection from the subsets of $\mathbb{N}$ to the open sets?

Comment: @Jessy: To establish the cardinality of the topology?

Comment: @AsafKaragila yes.I'm pretty new to this and I'm trying to get the hang of it.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Is it like $f(U) = \max\{n | B_{n} \subset U\}$ or something? And in order to use Cantor-Bernstein, you need an injection going the other way as well, so I was curious as to know what it was. It's not clear to me from either the OP's original post or this answer/ensuing comment thread.

Comment: @Jessy: The function is well defined within the body of my answer. $f(U)$ is the set of *all* $n$ such that $B_n$ is a subset of $U$.

Comment: This anwer does not explain why the euclidean topology has a countable basis (and, in particular, why this doesn't depend on choice) but Noah Schweber's answer does.

Comment: @ArvidSamuelsson: Are you going through all my answers through the years to criticise each and every one of them? Just so I understand what's going on.

Comment: @AsafKaragila No, I just follow the links between the questions and comment when I have something to say.

Answer (score 12):

You don't need choice here at all - every open set $U$ has a *canonical* description in terms of basic open sets, $code(U)=\{B_\eta: B_\eta\subseteq U\}$ (where $\{B_\eta: \eta<\omega\}$ is the set of all balls with rational radius and center). We clearly have $code(U)=code(V)\iff U=V$, and the set of codes has size continuum.